# Why there is a data race

Tags: go

I was reading Dave Cheney's post https://dave.cheney.net/2015/11/18/wednesday-pop-quiz-spot-the-race, but couldn't understand why the example contains data race. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should have an actual scenario in your question. Maybe showing some codes you got?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the relevant code from the blog post:

```
func (rpc *RPC) compute() {
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    rpc.result = 42   /* W */
    close(rpc.done)
}

func (RPC) version() int {
    return 1
}

⋮
go rpc.compute()         
version := rpc.version() /* R */
<-rpc.done
```

The goroutine modifies the caller's `rpc.result` field at the line notated by `/* W */`.  This is the easy part to understand.

The method call at the line notated by `/* R */` is syntactic sugar for `(*rpc).version()`.  The receiver value is copied on the method call, including the `result` field. The read is concurrent with the write at `/* W */` and is therefore a data race.  Although the program does not do anything with the copied `result` field, it's still a data race.

Fix by changing the `version()` method to use pointer receiver:

```
func (*RPC) version() int {
    return 1
}
```